# Rewrite default / (index.php) in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Currently, the server redirects any HTTP request to http://www.example.com/index.php to HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However the problem is when a request is made to http://www.example.com, as then no redirection is being done.

How can I make the server redirect to HTTPS in the case of an empty {REQUEST_URI}. (I'm assuming it's empty)

**Edit:** 

After akostadinov's answer, I modified the .htaccess to include this, and the rewriting worked. I'll post it here in case someone has the same problem later!

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request is `/`. See `curl -v` output below (trunkated). btw you may omit the URI condition if you don't really need to match a specific one.

```
$ curl -v example.com
* About to connect() to example.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.0.43.10...
* connected
* Connected to example.com (192.0.43.10) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
...
```

Comment: It's weird. I did some changes  to the .htaccess before seeing your question, didn't work. Then when I reset it to its original code, it started redirecting the / without any additional changes.. I hate it when things like that happen. I can't figure out what was wrong now.. Thank you for your answer though! If anyone has any comments on this please let me know. I'd like to know more.

Comment: Ok just tried it again today and it didn't work! I made the condition for the / to be redirected and it worked! Thank you for your help!